# select the last 2 values ​in the groupby with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to select the rows of the last value for each **user_id** and **date**, but when the last value in the **metric** column is 'leave' select the last 2 rows(if exists).
My data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     "user_id": [1,1,1, 2,2,2]
    ,'subscription': [1,1,2,3,4,5]
    ,"metric": ['enter', 'stay', 'leave', 'enter', 'leave', 'enter']
    ,'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02']
})
#result
    user_id subscription    metric  date
0   1       1               enter   2020-01-01
1   1       1               stay    2020-01-01
2   1       2               leave   2020-03-01
3   2       3               enter   2020-01-01
4   2       4               leave   2020-01-01
5   2       5               enter   2020-01-02
```

Expected output:

```
    user_id subscription    metric  date
1   1       1               stay    2020-01-01
2   1       2               leave   2020-03-01
3   2       3               enter   2020-01-01 # stay because last metric='leave' inside group[user_id, date]
4   2       4               leave   2020-01-01
5   2       5               enter   2020-01-02
```

What I've tried: `drop_duplicates` and `groupby`, both give the same result, only with the last value

```
df.drop_duplicates(['user_id', 'date'], keep='last')
#or
df.groupby(['user_id', 'date']).tail(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean masking and return three different conditions that are `True` or `False` with variables `a`, `b`, or `c`. Then, filter for when the data a, b, or c returns `True` with the or operator `|`:

```
a = df.groupby(['user_id', 'date', df.groupby(['user_id', 'date']).cumcount()])['metric'].transform('last') == 'leave'
b = df.groupby(['user_id', 'date'])['metric'].transform('count') == 1
c = a.shift(-1) & (b == False)
df = df[a | b | c]
print(a, b, c)
df

#a groupby the two required groups plus a group that finds the cumulative count, which is necessary in order to return True for the last "metric" within the the group.
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: metric, dtype: bool

#b if something has a count of one, then you want to keep it.
0    False
1    False
2    True
3    False
4    False
5    True
Name: metric, dtype: bool

#c simply use .shift(-1) to find the row before the row. For the condition to be satisfied the count for that group must be > 1
0    False
1    True
2    False
3    True
4    False
5    False
Name: metric, dtype: bool

Out[18]: 
   user_id  subscription metric        date
1        1             1   stay  2020-01-01
2        1             2  leave  2020-03-01
3        2             3  enter  2020-01-01
4        2             4  leave  2020-01-01
5        2             5  enter  2020-01-02
```

Comment: much better solution +1. still needs some tweaks

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy appreciate it, what do you think I could tweak to improve this?

Comment: you are missing row 5

Comment: aah @sammywemmy , that is a typo on my part. Accidentally deleted that row when copy and pasting. Thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, but in my opinion, slow, since we are iterating through the grouping :

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df.assign(metric_is_leave=df.metric.eq("leave"))

pd.concat(
    [
        value.iloc[-2:, :-1] if value.metric_is_leave.any() else value.iloc[-1:, :-1]
        for key, value in df.groupby(["user_id", "date"])
    ]
)




  user_id   subscription    metric  date
1      1        1           stay    2020-01-01
2      1        2          leave    2020-03-01
3      2        3          enter    2020-01-01
4      2        4          leave    2020-01-01
5      2        5          enter    2020-01-02
```